# How to receive the password for stackexchange account?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I registered on some sites of stackexchange.com such as stackoverflow and others. I registered by using Google ID. I need to get password and username to access stackexchange. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

All the stack exchange related sites can use open ID, including Google. Click on the [log in page](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f) and select Google. Use your Google account id and password.